# Dynamically add description for Facebook share dialog

Tags: parameter-passing, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, facebook-sharer, facebook-sdk-3.0

I want to implement Facebook sharing on my webpage. I have done that with by following this link: [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/) (XFBML). The **image**, **title** and **description** in my share dialog are loaded via meta-tags, that are placed at the `<head>` of the page:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="<<here it goes the title>>" /> 
<meta property="og:image" content="<<here it goes the URL to the image>>"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="<facebook user-name> Liked <here it goes data that is related to passed ID form URL>
```

The image and the title are not a problem, they will always remain the same. But I need a different description for different pages. (For better understanding, please **follow only the red lines** in the image below). In the URL I'm passing some ID, and on the base of that ID, I want to retrieve some data from my database. I can do that in the body of the page, but I don't know how to pass the parameter for description (summary) in my Facebook share dialog. The only working technique that I found on Google is passing the parameters via meta tags. So as I said, I can get the data I need in the body, but when I'am in the body, the head (along with meta tags) is already loaded and changing them in jQuery is not taking effect.

[image: follow the red lines only]

the share button dialog is implemented following these instructions, and I can not find out how to add description:

[image]

Is there any solution of how to pass the description with the data described above?
BTW. I don't have Facebook app associated with my webpage, so if it's possible I want to solve this without creating one, but if the solution require one, than I will have to create it.

At this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443680/add-facebook-username-in-facebook-share-dialog) I have another question related to my problem for sharing, but I put them at separated posts because I think that the solutions are from different domains, and any help will be appreciated, even if I solve only one of these two problems.